# ScrollTop on overflow:hidden list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have a simple list that I want to reset to the top position every time the click button is clicked. I can't seem to get my scrollTop to work though and I can't figure out why.

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zj8d/)

HTML:

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <ul id="list">
        <li id="first">item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="click">CLICK</button>
```

CSS:

```
.listContainer {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:grey;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
ul#list {
    background:grey;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
li {
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('listContainer').scrollTop() + $('li#first').position().top;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having **two elements with overflow-y: scroll;** one inside the other?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean to use `$('listContainer')` and not like `$('.listContainer')`? Also, why bother getting the top? Wouldn't `.scrollTop(0)` do the trick if you need to go to the top?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zj8d/1/)**

CSS:

```
ul#list {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
   $('#list').scrollTop(0);
});
```

- When using jsFidde you need to include the desired *Library* in your case **jQuery**
- There's no need to have two elements with `overflow-y:scroll;` one inside the other.
- If you need a click event than create one.
- Target the **one element** you decided to have `overflow-y` and use `.scrollTop(0)`
- you want an scroll animation? http://jsfiddle.net/5zj8d/2/